# How to combine multiple queries in single in Sequalize, Mysql, Node

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, count, pivot

I want to get the 4 types of counts based on type, for that I have 4 individual queries, but I want to use only one single query to get all 4 counts at a time.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT count(*) as totalCount FROM orders INNER JOIN order_view ON orders.id= order_view.id 
WHERE order_view.order_type = 'Type1'
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT count(*) as totalCount FROM orders INNER JOIN order_view ON orders.id= order_view.id 
WHERE order_view.order_type = 'Type2'
```

**Query 3:**

```
SELECT count(*) as totalCount FROM orders INNER JOIN order_view ON orders.id= order_view.id 
WHERE order_view.order_type = 'Type3'
```

**Query 4:**

```
SELECT count(*) as totalCount FROM orders INNER JOIN order_view ON orders.id= order_view.id 
WHERE order_view.order_type = 'Type4'
```

I am looking for the query through Sequelize and cannot seem to find any documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(ov.order_type = 'type1') as totalcount1,
    sum(ov.order_type = 'type2') as totalcount2
    sum(ov.order_type = 'type3') as totalcount3
    sum(ov.order_type = 'type4') as totalcount4
from orders o
inner join order_view on o.id = ov.id 
where ov.order_type in ('type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4')
```

It is unclear why you need table `orders` in the query at all. This might just do what you want:

```
select 
    sum(ov.order_type = 'type1') as totalcount1,
    sum(ov.order_type = 'type2') as totalcount2
    sum(ov.order_type = 'type3') as totalcount3
    sum(ov.order_type = 'type4') as totalcount4
from order_view
where ov.order_type in ('type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4')
```

Comment: Actually the query was huge, I have trimmed it for better understanding